# How to select only unique values from this table based on criteria?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select only the first record from each group. So basically I only want the data for first processing date column and don't want the rest of the date for each product.

My current code as below

```
SELECT  
C.AccountID as ABN_ACC , 
C.ProductSymbol, 
C.ProductShortName, 
S.ReactorProduct  AS REC_PROD, 
C.CurrencyCode AS PROD_CCY,
C.CountryOfPayment AS PAYCONTRY,
C.DividendValueCur AS PAYCCY, 
C.DividendValue AS DIV_AMNT,
CONCAT ((IIF (C.QuantitySettledNoTax_LS = 'S' ,(-1*C.QuantitySettledNoTax),C.QuantitySettledNoTax )),(IIF(C.QuantitySettledTax_LS = 'S',(-1*C.QuantitySettledTax),QuantitySettledTax))) AS DIVQTY ,
C.ExdividendDate AS EXDATE, 
C.Recorddate AS RECDATE, 
C.DividendPayDate AS PAYDATE
From "LiquidCDW". [Staging].[CA_CorporateActions] AS C
RIGHT JOIN "LiquidCDW".[Staging].[POS_SettledPositions] AS P ON C.Recorddate = P.ProcessingDate AND C.AccountID = p.AccountID AND C.ProductSymbol = P.ProductSymbol AND C.DividendValueCur = P.CurrencyCode 
INNER JOIN "LiquidCDW".[Transformation].[Mapping_Product_ABNReactor] AS S ON C.ProductSymbol = S.ReactorProduct AND S.ValidTo IS NULL AND S.ProductType = 'E' AND c.DividendValueCur = S.Currency 
where C.ExdividendDate >= '20210201'
ORDER by C.ProductSymbol , C.CurrencyCode
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One approach uses `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C.ProductSymbol ORDER BY processingDate) rn,
        C.AccountID AS ABN_ACC,
        C.ProductSymbol,
        C.ProductShortName,
        S.ReactorProduct AS REC_PROD,
        C.CurrencyCode AS PROD_CCY,
        C.CountryOfPayment AS PAYCONTRY,
        C.DividendValueCur AS PAYCCY,
        C.DividendValue AS DIV_AMNT,
        CONCAT((IIF(C.QuantitySettledNoTax_LS = 'S',
               (-1*C.QuantitySettledNoTax), C.QuantitySettledNoTax)),
               (IIF(C.QuantitySettledTax_LS = 'S',
               (-1*C.QuantitySettledTax),QuantitySettledTax))) AS DIVQTY,
        C.ExdividendDate AS EXDATE,
        C.Recorddate AS RECDATE,
        C.DividendPayDate AS PAYDATE
    FROM [LiquidCDW].[Staging].[CA_CorporateActions] AS C
    RIGHT JOIN "LiquidCDW".[Staging].[POS_SettledPositions] AS P
        ON C.Recorddate = P.ProcessingDate AND
           C.AccountID = p.AccountID AND
           C.ProductSymbol = P.ProductSymbol AND
           C.DividendValueCur = P.CurrencyCode 
    INNER JOIN [LiquidCDW].[Transformation].[Mapping_Product_ABNReactor] AS S
        ON C.ProductSymbol = S.ReactorProduct AND
           S.ValidTo IS NULL AND
           S.ProductType = 'E' AND
           C.DividendValueCur = S.Currency 
    WHERE
        C.ExdividendDate >= '20210201'
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY ProductSymbol, CurrencyCode;
```